# knockout's viewModel does not get updated

Tags: json, knockout.js, updatemodel

I have the following knockout's viewModel :

var viewModel={
  businessName:  "",
    ....
 }

I also tried to identify the field like this: businessName:  ko.observable("")

Then, I have a load method that requests for a JSon with a newly populated data

And this is how I'm trying to apply the new data:

```
$.ajax({
                       //
                       url: "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Load"))",
                       type: "post",
                       data: ko.toJSON(this),
                       contentType: "application/json",
                       success: function (result) {

     //OPTION 1:
                           viewModel.businessName = result.vm.BusinessName;

     //OPTION 2:
                           var viewModel2 = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.vm);
                           console.log(viewModel2.businessName);



                       }
                   });//ajax
```

As a result:
if I use Option1, I get the new data but it does not get updated on the page.
If I use Option2, it writes "undefined"

Please advise how can I update the new data on the page?
I checked the similar topics but there is no answer that helps

PS

It seems I resolved OPTION 1. But still don't understand why OPTION 2 does not work

Answer (score 0):

`ko.observable` is a function, not a property. So you get it's value like this:

```
var whatsTheValue = myVM.MyObservable();
```

and you set it like this:

```
myVM.MyObservable(newValue);
```

This is all in the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

Note, however, when using the `data-bind` syntax in your HTML, you don't need to explicitly unwrap your observable by using the parenthesis because KO is smart enough to do it automatically:

```
<span data-bind="text: MyObservable"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **have** to use `ko.observable` in the ViewModel and access/write it accordingly.

```
var myViewModel = {
    businessName = ko.observable('')
};

...

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(result) {
        myViewModel.businessName(result.vm.BusinessName);
    },
    ...
});
```

Otherwise your view won't have any clue you changed `businessName`. In the implementation ko.observable, besides actually storing the new value, broadcasts some events to your view, letting it know the stored value changed.